# CodeIgniter new controller not found?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I installed latest CodeIgniter and copied welcome.php to backend.php, and changed the class variable to Backend however when I go to /backend it says controller not found.  The contents of my .htaccess are as follows.

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also tried to change the uri method to request uri, still the same issue.

The index controller works, but not the backend which was created from the index. (welcome.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the class name defined in backend.php is `Backend`:

```
class Backend extends CI_Controller { ... }
```

Make sure you have a method `index` (default action) in the `Backend` controller:

```
 public function index() { ... }
```

PS: You could also create a new directory `backend` and put there ALL your controllers that you need in the backend. This would make things easier if you have complex functionality in the backend area.

Comment: Strange, I had to delete the comments from the original welcome file for it to work.  I am going to choose your answer because the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

YOu will need a htaccess file that has the following written in it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that the controller can be accessed by adding /index in the URL and then the controller name.

Therefore, you need a htaccess file to remove that issue.